# Change invoice sequence when currency changes

Tags: invoice, multicurrency

I have a store which has 2 currencies INR and EUR, when a invoice is raised against any order it assigns it a invoice number. This invoice number follows same sequence for both the currencies. What I need is to have separate series for both.

Thanks for your help.